# Derivative of the variance of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a stochastic process on $\mathbb{R}$ with independent increments. Then, assuming that all the relevant quantities exist, one can prove by simple algebraic manipulations that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}Var(X_t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \frac{E((X_{t+\Delta t}-X_t)^2)}{\Delta t}.
$$

At the end of this short PDF ([https://sites.me.ucsb.edu/~moehlis/moehlis_papers/appendix.pdf](https://sites.me.ucsb.edu/%7Emoehlis/moehlis_papers/appendix.pdf)) the authors make a comment that seems to suggest that the same conclusion also holds in the case of a time-homogeneous Markov process without the hypothesis of independent increments. Is that actually true? And if yes, how can it be proved?

To give some context, this question arose from a step in the derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation (see linked PDF). Indeed, it could also be stated as
$$
D^{(2)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}Var(X_t),
$$
where $D^{(2)}$ is the second Kramers-Moyal coefficient.

Comment: A lot of assumptions on existence of second moments, existence of limit etc, are needed for this even when the increments are independent. Your statement is too vague.

Comment: Well, no assumptions other than the existence of the various quantities are needed (that is, as you pointed out, of the second moments and of the derivative). What's more the LHS is well defined iff the RHS is well defined, since the statement could be given with incremental quotients in place of limits.

Comment: If $X_t=tX$ where $X\sim N(0,1)$ then LHS is $t^{2}$ and RHS is $0$.

Comment: The LHS is $2t$ because we take the derivative. Anyway, many thanks, this simple counter-example answers the question as I asked it. Unfortunately, however, I am actually interested in the case of a time-homogeneous Markov process (my fault, I forgot to mention it, now I've edited). Can you perhaps find a counter-example that is also time homogeneous?